# Insert large volume data into SQL Server via c# in a single database call

Tags: c#, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Speed up update of 185k rows in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292644/speed-up-update-of-185k-rows-in-sql-server-2008)

I have more than 700.000 contact mails and I want to insert them into SQL Server using C#, in a few minutes, not hours, in a single database call.

I know that pre is impossible but, I know there's way to do it

how can I achieve this?

Comment: See [my reply about using bulk copy + an optional merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292644/speed-up-update-of-185k-rows-in-sql-server-2008/12379039#12379039), which is the fastest approach that *I* know of.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at using [SqlBulkCopy Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)

> Lets you efficiently bulk load a SQL Server table with data from
>   another source.
>
> Microsoft SQL Server includes a popular command-prompt utility named
>   bcp for moving data from one table to another, whether on a single
>   server or between servers. The SqlBulkCopy class lets you write
>   managed code solutions that provide similar functionality. There are
>   other ways to load data into a SQL Server table (INSERT statements,
>   for example), but SqlBulkCopy offers a significant performance
>   advantage over them.